# Magnific Gallery открывает url картинки

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, magnific, magnific-popup

Мне нужно, чтобы галарея открывалась в виде pop up, почему не работает?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>



<section class="pt-0">
  <div id="gallery" class="gallerys container-fluid">
    <a class='project_flex gallery-image' href='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1697403704196-e08fb51fc0cd?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1974&q=80'>
      <figure class='gallery-image'>
        <img height='250px' src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1697403704196-e08fb51fc0cd?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1974&q=80'>
      </figure>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gallerys').magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      delegate: 'a',

      closeOnContentClick: true,
      closeBtnInside: false,
      mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
      image: {
        verticalFit: true,
        titleSrc: function(item) {
          return item.el.find('figcaption').text() || item.el.attr('title');
        }
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: true
      },
      // duration: 300
      gallery: {
        enabled: true,
        navigateByImgClick: false,
        tCounter: ''
      },

    })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Привет, Nadja! А пробовали ли вы добавлять свои стили для отображения нужного результата модального окна?